# Click on an area of an image, then type answer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a hotspot game, where users click on an area of an image, a text box appears and the user can type what they think the answer is.

If the answer is correct, 1 point is added to the user's score, and the hotspot is rendered unclickable.

I've made a start on the basic idea here:

https://codepen.io/Punchyoual/pen/oGXqyg

HTML

```
<div class="cat_container">
  <div id="score-container">
    <div id="score"></div>/10</div>


  <div class="hotspot hotspot_1 clickable1"></div>
  <div class="hotspot hotspot_2 clickable2"></div>
  <div class="hotspot hotspot_3 clickable3"></div>

  <div class="guess_box1 guess">
    <a class="close" id="close_guess_box1">X</a>
    <input type="text" class="answer" id="hotspot_1_answer"></input>
  </div>

  <div class="guess_box2 guess">
    <a class="close" id="close_guess_box2">X</a>
    <input type="text" class="answer" id="hotspot_2_answer"></input>
  </div>

  <div class="guess_box3 guess">
    <a class="close" id="close_guess_box3">X</a>
    <input type="text" class="answer" id="hotspot_3_answer"></input>
  </div>


  <div id="correct" style="display:none;"><H1 style="padding-top:160px;">Correct!</H1></div>
  <div id="incorrect" style="display:none;"><H1 style="padding-top:160px;">You're Wrong!<H1></div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".close").click(function() {
  $(".answer").val('');
});

//Click Areas

$(".clickable1").click(function() {
  $(".guess_box1").show();
  $('#hotspot_1_answer').focus();
  $(".guess").not(".guess_box1").each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  })
});

$(".clickable2").click(function() {
  $(".guess_box2").show();
   $('#hotspot_2_answer').focus();
  $(".guess").not(".guess_box2").each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  })
});

$(".clickable3").click(function() {
  $(".guess_box3").show();
   $('#hotspot_3_answer').focus();
  $(".guess").not(".guess_box3").each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  })
});

//Close Guess boxes

$("#close_guess_box1").click(function() {
  $(".guess_box1").hide(300);
});

$("#close_guess_box2").click(function() {
  $(".guess_box2").hide(300);
});

$("#close_guess_box3").click(function() {
  $(".guess_box3").hide(300);
});



var score = 0;


$("#score").text(score);

$("#hotspot_1_answer").keypress(function(e) {

  if (e.which == 13) {

    var text = $('#hotspot_1_answer').val().toLowerCase();
    if (text == 'eye') {

      $(".guess_box1").remove();
      $("#answer_box").show();
      $("#correct").show();
      $(".hotspot_1").removeClass('clickable').addClass('hotspot_done'); 
      $('#correct').delay(1000).fadeOut();
      score++;
      $("#score").text(score);


    } else {

      $(".guess_box1").hide(100);
      $("#answer_box").show();
      $("#incorrect").show();
      $('#incorrect').delay(1000).fadeOut();
      $("#hotspot_1_answer").val('');

    }
  }
});

$("#hotspot_2_answer").keypress(function(e) {

  if (e.which == 13) {

    var text = $('#hotspot_2_answer').val().toLowerCase();
    if (text == 'ear') {

      $(".guess_box2").remove();
      $("#answer_box").show();
      $("#correct").show();
      $(".hotspot_2").removeClass('clickable').addClass('hotspot_done'); 
      $('#correct').delay(1000).fadeOut();
      score++;
      $("#score").text(score);


    } else {

      $(".guess_box2").hide(100);
      $("#answer_box").show();
      $("#incorrect").show();
      $('#incorrect').delay(1000).fadeOut();
      $("#hotspot_2_answer").val('');

    }
  }
});

$("#hotspot_3_answer").keypress(function(e) {

  if (e.which == 13) {

    var text = $('#hotspot_3_answer').val().toLowerCase();
    if (text == 'tail') {

      $(".guess_box3").remove();
      $("#answer_box").show();
      $("#correct").show();
      $(".hotspot_3").removeClass('clickable').addClass('hotspot_done'); 
      $('#correct').delay(1000).fadeOut();
      score++;
      $("#score").text(score);


    } else {

      $(".guess_box3").hide(100);
      $("#answer_box").show();
      $("#incorrect").show();
      $('#incorrect').delay(1000).fadeOut();
      $("#hotspot_3_answer").val('');

    }
  }
});
```

I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution to this, without using multiple answer boxes. I feel like i need to use data-attributes, and check the answer with JQuery, but i'm not really sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we don't need to write seperate click events for every clickable area as that generate redundent code. Just have a common class in all clickable area and bind it to a single event handler and check which clickable area is being clicked in code.

HTML

```
<div class="hotspot hotspot_1 clickable"></div>
<div class="hotspot hotspot_2 clickable"></div>
<div class="hotspot hotspot_3 clickable"></div>
```

jQuery

```
let lastClickedClass = '';
$(".clickable").click(function () { 
    if($(this).hasClass('hotspot_1')){
        lastClickedClass = '.hotspot_1';
    }else if ($(this).hasClass('hotspot_2')){
        lastClickedClass = '.hotspot_2';
    }else if ($(this).hasClass('hotspot_3')){
        lastClickedClass = '.hotspot_3';
    }

    $(".guess_box").show();
    $('#hotspot_answer').focus();
    $(".guess").not(".guess_box").each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    })
});
```

Next, We don't need different input for answers, as that will just increase number of input for every clickable area you add on the page. So you can just have one guess_box with the input and one keypress event to bind to.

HTML

```
<div class="guess_box guess">
    <a class="close" id="close_guess_box">X</a>
    <input type="text" class="answer" id="hotspot_answer">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#hotspot_answer").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var text = $('#hotspot_answer').val().toLowerCase();
        var isCorrect = true;
        if(!((text === 'eye' && lastClickedClass==='.hotspot_1') 
            || (text === 'ear' && lastClickedClass==='.hotspot_2') 
            || (text === 'tail' && lastClickedClass==='.hotspot_3'))){
                isCorrect = false;
        }

        if (isCorrect) {
            $(".guess_box").hide();
            $("#hotspot_answer").val('');
            $("#answer_box").show();
            $("#correct").show();                    
            $(lastClickedClass).off('click');
            $('#correct').delay(1000).fadeOut();
            score++;
            $("#score").text(score);
        } else {
            $(".guess_box").hide(100);
            $("#answer_box").show();
            $("#incorrect").show();
            $('#incorrect').delay(1000).fadeOut();
            $("#hotspot_answer").val('');
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fw4L6a3x/3/) for the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works - so much more efficient than my method!